Enriching DataStream using updatable Data in Flink streaming
I am writing a Flink streaming program in which I need to enrich a DataStream with some data (~10GB) that updates every 24 hours
If it is static data I can load it as key-value state before start of the streaming pipeline, but how can i update it every 24 hours? Or maybe somehow update it in background?

Create a custom source (extends sourceFunction) that pull the data every 24 hr

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
